# Is There a “Reset” Button Available for the Web Chat?

Tags: botframework, direct-line-botframework, web-chat

Out of the box, the default set of buttons of the web chat is a "Send" button and an "Upload File" button.  Does the web chat have available a "Reset" button that would end the current conversation and start a new conversation from the beginning for the same user?  Is there some configuration or style options that I need to turn on to get and see visually a "Reset" button.

The chat/conversation history needs to stay intact. It should not clear out.

I'm currently using JavaScript to setup the web chat and using direct line channel to talk to my bot.  I have made some UI customizations using the botframework-webchat style options.  Pls note, there is no iframe involved for the web chat.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fyj97.png)

```js
var directLineObj = window.WebChat.createDirectLine({

    token: "..."
});

// For additional style options:
// https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/blob/master/packages/component/src/Styles/defaultStyleOptions.js
const styleOptions = {

    ...
};

var options = {

    directLine: directLineObj,
    styleOptions: styleOptions
};

var containerObj = document.getElementById("chatContainer");

var webChatObj = window.WebChat.renderWebChat(options, containerObj);
```

```html
<div id="chatContainer" class="..."></div>
```

Comment: Do you mean that you want the user to be able to restart the conversation? If so, you will need logic in your botcode to (and an event from interface to your botcode to initiate it)

Comment: hi @Hessel, so there is nothing out of the box that I can turn on where on the UI of the web chat, I would see a "Reset" button, is that correct?

Comment: Unfortunately there is nothing out of the box for that. So yes, you need to implement a custom feature for that.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this by using a button (or implementation of your choice) coupled with sending an activity via Web Chat plus the [cancel / interrupt component dialog](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/main/samples/javascript_nodejs/13.core-bot/dialogs/cancelAndHelpDialog.js) of the [13.core-bot](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/javascript_nodejs/13.core-bot) sample (example below uses JS SDK, but is available in the other SDKs).

**Web Chat:** When the `button` is clicked, Web Chat dispatches `WEB_CHAT/SEND_ACTIVITY` that includes the text 'reset'.

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/markdown-it@8.4.2/dist/markdown-it.min.js"></script>
  <script crossorigin="anonymous" src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone@7.8.7/babel.min.js"></script>
  <script crossorigin="anonymous" src="https://unpkg.com/regenerator-runtime@0.13.3/runtime.js"></script>
  <script crossorigin="anonymous" src="https://unpkg.com/react@16.8.6/umd/react.development.js"></script>
  <script crossorigin="anonymous" src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.8.6/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
  <script crossorigin="anonymous" src="https://unpkg.com/react-redux@7.1.0/dist/react-redux.min.js"></script>
  <script crossorigin="anonymous" src="https://cdn.botframework.com/botframework-webchat/latest/webchat.js"></script>
  <style>
    html,
    body {
      height: 100%
    }

    body {
      margin: 0
    }

    #webchat {
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%s;
    }

  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="webchat" role="main"></div>
  <button id='resetBtn' type="button">Reset Dialog</button>

  <script type="text/babel" data-presets="es2015,react,stage-3">
    ( async function () {
      // 'use strict';
      const { ReactDOM: { render }, WebChat: { ReactWebChat } } = window;

      const store = window.WebChat.createStore( {}, ( { dispatch } ) => next => action => {
        return next( action );
      } );

      const res = await fetch( 'http://localhost:3500/directline/token', { method: 'POST' } );
      let { token } = await res.json();

      await render(
        <ReactWebChat
          directLine={await window.WebChat.createDirectLine( {token} )}
          store={store}
        />,
        document.getElementById( 'webchat' )
      );
      document.querySelector( '#webchat > *' ).focus();

      const resetBtn = document.getElementById( 'resetBtn' );
      resetBtn.addEventListener( 'click', ( e ) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        store.dispatch( {
          type: 'WEB_CHAT/SEND_MESSAGE',
          payload: {
            text: `Reset`
          }
        } )
      } )

    } )().catch( err => console.error( err ) );     
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

**cancelAndHelpDialog.js:** When the 'reset' activity is received by the bot, it then calls `cancelAllDialogs(true)` clearing the stack and returning the bot to the initial dialog.

```js
async interrupt(innerDc) {
  if (innerDc.context && innerDc.context.activity) {
    const { activity } = innerDc.context;
    if (activity.text) {
      const text = activity.text;
      const activityText = text.toLowerCase();
      let message = '';

      switch (activityText) {
        case 'reset': {
          message = 'Request approved: resetting dialog';
          const resetMessage = MessageFactory.text(message, message, InputHints.IgnoringInput);
          resetMessage.channelData = { action: 'dialog_reset' };
          await innerDc.context.sendActivity(resetMessage);
          return await innerDc.cancelAllDialogs(true);
        }
        case 'help':
          case '?': {
            message = 'Show help here';
            await innerDc.context.sendActivity(message, message, InputHints.ExpectingInput);
            return { status: DialogTurnStatus.waiting };
        }
        case 'cancel':
        case 'quit': {
          message = 'Cancelling...';
          await innerDc.context.sendActivity(message, message, InputHints.IgnoringInput);
          return await innerDc.beginDialog(EXIT_DIALOG);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This is fairly bare bones and will likely require some 'clean up" to meet your needs, including some sort of response showing the dialog is restarting.

Hope of help!