# How can I get response from the server without creating directline object everytime in Microsoft Bot Framework Direct Line JS Client (REACTJS)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, botframework, direct-line-botframework

I am passing `getResponse()` function in the useEffect with `userInput` as dependency array. Everytime a user sends input this function is triggered and I get new directline object created everytime. Problem I am facing is that I am creating bot everytime I send a request to bot. How can I create an object only once on initial render and then use the object to connect with bot.

Please help!

[Here's the botframework documentation I am following](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-DirectLineJS)

Here's the code I wrote to communicate with bot in ReactJS.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./App.css"
import { DirectLine } from "botframework-directlinejs";
import { browserName, browserVersion, osName } from "react-device-detect";
import { ConnectionStatus } from 'botframework-directlinejs';
import Header from "./Components/Header";
import MainBody from "./Components/MainBody";
import BottomWrapper from "./Components/BottomWrapper";

function App() {
  useEffect(() => {
    const userIpDetails = fetchIp();
    setUserIp(userIpDetails);
  }, []);

  // to fetch user IP
  const fetchIp = async () => {
    const response = await fetch("https://api.ipify.org/?format=json");
    const ip = await response.json();
    const userIP = ip.ip;
    return userIP;
  };

  const [loaded, setLoaded] = useState(false);
  const [message, setMessage] = useState("");
  const [userInput, setUserInput] = useState([]);
  const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);
  const [userIp, setUserIp] = useState("");

  var client;

  useEffect(() => {
    setLoaded(true);
    getResponse();
  }, [userInput]);

  // to get DirectLine Streaming Token
  const getDirectLineStreamingToken = async function () {
    const res = await fetch(
      https://directline.botframework.com/v3/directline/tokens/generate,
      {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          Authorization:
            `Bearer TOKEN`,
        },
      }
    );
    const { token } = await res.json();
    return token;
  };

  // send request via message box
  const sendRequest = () => {
    console.log("request sent");
    client
      ?.postActivity({
        from: {
          id: "my_id",
          name: "Software Company",
          avatarUrl:
            "https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/content/chat/VacationBot.png",
        },
        type: "message",
        text: message,
        channelData: {
          iP: userIp,
          platform: `${osName}`,
          Browser: `${browserName} ${browserVersion}`,
        },
      })
      ?.subscribe(
        (id) => console.log("Posted activity, assigned ID ", id),
        (error) => console.log("Error posting activity", error)
      );
  };

  // receive response from server
  const getResponse = function () {
    getDirectLineStreamingToken().then(function (token) {
      client = new DirectLine({
        domain: "https://directline.botframework.com/v3/directline",
        token: token,
      });

      client.activity$.subscribe((activity) => {
        onResponse(activity);
      });

      client.connectionStatus$
      .subscribe(connectionStatus => {
          switch(connectionStatus) {
              case ConnectionStatus.Uninitialized:    // the status when the DirectLine object is first created/constructed
              case ConnectionStatus.Connecting:       // currently trying to connect to the conversation
              case ConnectionStatus.Online:           // successfully connected to the converstaion. Connection is healthy so far as we know.
              case ConnectionStatus.ExpiredToken:     // last operation errored out with an expired token. Your app should supply a new one.
              case ConnectionStatus.FailedToConnect:  // the initial attempt to connect to the conversation failed. No recovery possible.
              case ConnectionStatus.Ended:            // the bot ended the conversation
          }
          console.log("connection status ", connectionStatus)
      });
    })
    .catch((e) => console.log("bot error", e));;
  };

  // handle response received from server
  const onResponse = function (activity) {
    console.log("activity is ", activity);
    let receivedResponse = activity.text;
    if (activity.inputHint === "acceptingInput") {
      setMessages([
        ...messages,
        { messageKey: receivedResponse, isbotmessage: true },
      ]);
    }
  };

  const handleChange = function (event) {
    setMessage(event.target.value);
    console.log(event.target.value);
  };

  const handleKeyPress = function (event) {
    if (event.key === "Enter") {
      sendRequest();
      setMessages([...messages, { messageKey: message, isbotmessage: false }]);
      setUserInput([
        ...messages,
        { messageKey: userInput, isbotmessage: false },
      ]);
    }
  };

  const handleClick = function (event) {
    sendRequest();
    setMessages([...messages, { messageKey: message, isbotmessage: false }]);
    setUserInput([...messages, { messageKey: userInput, isbotmessage: false }]);
  };

  return loaded ? (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="chat-window">
        <Header />
        <MainBody messages={messages}/>
        <BottomWrapper message={message} handleChange={handleChange} handleKeyPress={handleKeyPress} handleClick={handleClick}/>
      </div>
    </div>
  ) : (
    <p>Loading...</p>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should move the creation of the DirectLine `client` object, as well as subscribing to `activity` and `connectionStatus`, out of the function *or* configure the useEffect() hook to run only once. The `client` object should be created once and then referenced, as needed. Check out this SO [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64864575/3962636) that discusses how to implement these options.

Additionally, because you already subscribe to `activity` and `connectionStatus`, these should be allowed to run independently so they can function as expected. When the `connectionStatus` changes, the switch statement will detect this. As the different cases are met, you could assign the status thru `useState()` and detect the changes to state thru the `useEffect()` hook.