# Update Bot Framework WebChat SendBox Text

Tags: javascript, reactjs, botframework, web-chat

I want to update the text in my `WebChat` `SendBox`, using the following code in the Console on Edge:

```
window.WebChat.createStore().dispatch({
    type: 'WEB_CHAT/SET_SEND_BOX',
    payload: {
        text: 'Hello World',
    }
});
```

The Console returns:

```
{type: 'WEB_CHAT/SET_SEND_BOX', payload: {…}}
payload: {text: 'Hello World'}
type: "WEB_CHAT/SET_SEND_BOX"
[[Prototype]]: Object
```

But the `WebChat` `SendBox` is not updated with "Hello World".

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell from your code if you are already doing this, but you need to give the `createStore()` an assignment. Then, you need to pass that variable in as a parameter to Web Chat's render component.

Also, in the store, you should have it dispatch the `SET_SEND_BOX` action on `CONNECT_FULFILLED` or similar. If all you do is tell the store to dispatch the `SET_SEND_BOX` action as you have in your code, it will get called on *every* [action](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/main/packages/core/src/actions). This will effectively disallow anyone from typing in the send box as their input will always get overwritten.

```js
const store = window.WebChat.createStore( {}, ( { dispatch } ) => next => async action => {
  if ( action.type === 'DIRECT_LINE/CONNECT_FULFILLED' ) {
    store.dispatch( {
      type: 'WEB_CHAT/SET_SEND_BOX',
       payload: {
         text: 'Hello World'
       },
    } );
  };
  next( action );
} );

[ ... ]

window.WebChat.renderWebChat(
  {
    directLine: directLine,
    store: store
  },
  document.getElementById( 'webchat' )
);
```

Please look over the official BotFramework-WebChat [samples](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/main/samples). There are many examples on how to do this, and more.

Hope of help!

Comment: This is great, what if I want to trigger it from a button click on the page?

Comment: Look over this answer I [posted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64864575/3962636) to a similar question. They are using `ReactWebChat`, but don't let that distract you. The functionality is the same whichever you use.